# Javascript variable scope inside ajax function

Tags: javascript, ajax, scope

i know this is probably a stupid question and i know js scope questions are extremely common on SO, but could you possibly be kind enough to help me with this one anyway.

Here is my function:

```
function checkOpen(storeData) {
if (storeData.menu === 'true') {

    var offerImgPath = '/wcsstore/ConsumerDirectStorefrontAssetStore/images/colors/color'+ Brand.styleColour + '/v3/',
        offer1,
        offer2;

    cafeTabContent = '<p>Cafe/Restaurant facilities are available in this store.</p>';
    cafeTabContent += '<p class="menu_link"><a href="/store_menus/menu.pdf" target="_blank">Click here to download a menu</a></p>';

    if (Brand.storeLocatorSettings.cafeOffersOn === true) {

        $.ajax({
            url : Arcadia.Brand.storeLocatorSettings.offersPageURL,
            success : function(data) {
                var offerContainer = $(data).find('#basic_story_content');
                offer1 = offerContainer.children(':first-child').attr('src');
                offer2 = offerContainer.children(':last-child').attr('src');
            }
        });

        console.log(offer1);

        cafeTabContent += '<p>Current offers:</p>';
        cafeTabContent += '<p class="offer_graphic"><img src="' + offer1+ '" alt="Offer 1" /></p>';
        cafeTabContent += '<p class="offer_graphic"><img src="' + offer2+ '" alt="Offer 2" /></p>';
    }

    return cafeTabContent;
} else {
    return false;
}
};
```

The problem that i am having is that despite the fact that offer1 & offer2 are defined outside the ajax success function, the values applied within this function are not being maintained outside hence console.log(offer1) returns undefined instead of the image path. I know this is a scope question, and it is really bugging me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks guys, i knew it was just a case of me being stupid. Seeing as you all gave me the correct answer i'll give Ajinkya the credit seeing as he was first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ajax A means Asynchronous.
So console statement is executed before actual data is returned. It means after successful return value is assigned to offer1 and offer2 but you have printed it on console before that.
Try this

```
  $.ajax({
            url : Arcadia.Brand.storeLocatorSettings.offersPageURL,
            success : function(data) {
                var offerContainer = $(data).find('#basic_story_content');
                offer1 = offerContainer.children(':first-child').attr('src');
                offer2 = offerContainer.children(':last-child').attr('src');
        console.log(offer1);
        console.log(offer2);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're dealing with a different (though vaguely related) issue: the asynchronous nature of AJAX.

When your code invokes `$.ajax()`, that request is executed asynchronously and the code returns immediately when the request is sent. Thus `offer1` and `offer2` are still undefined.

The correct thing to do is to put *any* code that depends on the AJAX result into your `success` callback function (or a function called from said callback).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a scope problem. The problem is that by the time the ajax request completes and the callback gets called (setting `offer1` and `offer2`), the `console.log(...)` stuff is already long done.

Try it by putting another `console.log('ajax complete');` inside the callback, and notice that  it gets called last.

You can fix it by simply putting the rest of the function inside the callback, most probably.