# Variable becomes undefined during my function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have this jQuery function:

```
var searchResultsCounter = 0;
function searchPerson(filterText){
    //code
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType:"json",
        url: "res/main.php",
        data: { command : "loadPeople",
                filter: filterText },
        success: function( people ){
            for(var i = 0; i< people.length; i++){
                //code  
            }   
            searchResultsCounter = people.length;
            console.log(searchResultsCounter);  
        }
    }); 
console.log(searchResultsCounter);
return searchResultsCounter;
}
```

In the first console log, my `searchResultsCoutner` has a good value, at the second log, it becomes 0. Why is this happening?

Comment: Second one as in after the Ajax function? You know it is asynchronous right? So the last console.log in your code could be triggered before the one in your Ajax function.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791734/javascript-variable-scope-inside-ajax-function

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ajax request is executed asynchronously, so the `success` callback function which tries to alter the variable will be executed later.

Your function simply returns 0. You have to rewrite your code that it works an asynchronous way. One way would be to pass a callback function to `searchPerson` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Return from searchPerson() function the promise interface ($.ajax) and use returned result once deferred is resolved:

```
function searchPerson(filterText) {
    //code
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "res/main.php",
        data: {
            command: "loadPeople",
            filter: filterText
        }
    });
}

$.when(searchPerson(filterText)).done(function (data) { 
    /*SUCCESS*/
});
```

Comment: and the `data` paramaeter of the function, will contain the response from `main.php`?

Comment: Ya, it should return data from request